# How to Get Tables Data in out parameters of stored procedures in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I was trying to get data into the Output parameters of stored procedure in mysql but I am not getting it back.

Here's the query:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `get_initial_data`(
out usersData varchar(500), 
out employeesData varchar(500)
)

BEGIN

SELECT * into usersData FROM users;

SELECT * into employeesData FROM employees;

END
```

And here's how I call it:

```
Call get_initial_data(@users, @employees)

select @users

select @employees
```

I tried this and I am able to create the stored procedure, but I'm not able to call it, getting this error:

> Error Code: 1172. Result consisted of more than one row

Can you help me in this, am I passing the output parameters correctly and also the Data type of that?

Please let me know your response on this

Answer (score 0):

An output parameter can contain only a single value. You are trying to return result sets via the output variable. This is not how output parameters work.

You read the result sets coming from the procedure; no need to use output variables.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_initial_data()

BEGIN

SELECT * FROM users;
SELECT * FROM employees;

END
```

Output parameters are useful in a situation where you have a procedure calling another procedure and use the output of the called procedure. Even then, you can only use single values with output parameters.